# listbox control multiple selection how to store in database table in one customer id in asp.net c#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i want to insert multiple selected items from listbox control in asp.net webform to database table in one customer id so how to insert that record in one row.
in asp.net with c#
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctaKe.jpg)

Comment: You can make it a comma separated value when saving to DB.

Comment: But the best thing would be to have a mapper table with many to many relationship

Comment: give me any example code

Comment: show me what have you tried?

Comment: i'm confuse for that code so i did't try

Comment: give it a try first, Only if you start it you will learn how things work, even If I give you a solution you will not understand why somethings are put there. So I suggest you start it, put your efforts and then ask questions. Its my genuine suggestion, because I know once you start working you will learn yourself and have much better idea about stuff